# How generate Guid from entity framework when object created

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework

I have bound a datagrid to a context and add some rows at runtime but it generates an exception and couldn't save changes due to property of type Guid generates only empty Guid.

 How generate Guid from entity framework when object created?

Comment: I saw on the Entity Property properties on entity model a default value property but I tried Guid.NewGuid() but it didn't work.

Comment: I'm sorry, but this is really basic stuff. Please try using Google first next time.

Comment: I've googled it first, maybe I didn't query it well, anyway

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can decorate your Guid property with 
[[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.schema.databasegeneratedattribute%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)

```
[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
public Guid Id { get; set; }
```

This will generate a new row id every time you insert.

Comment: It's only .Net 4.5 or silverlight while I'm using 4.0

Comment: i'm gonna mark it as an answer even though I coudln't make it work in my code

Comment: What error are you getting? Or does it just not work? What version of Entity Framework are you using?

Comment: I coudln't find the apprpriate namespace or assembly to get it working

Comment: [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)] works for 4.5 and Silverlight.

Comment: You need to use Entity Framework 4.3.1, available in NuGet. I've just confirmed it works fine in .NET 4.0

Comment: Yes, you add it to your identity column (typically your Id column) in the entity model

Answer (score 0):

In other way, You can make a partial class for `YourEntity` like this:

```
public partial class YourEntity
{
   public Guid ID { get; set;}    
   public YourEntity()
   {
      ID = Guid.NewGuid();
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just change the property 'StoreGeneratedPattern' for the field to Identity.

So your Object 'SalesOrderHeader' has a field 'rowguid'. Just select the field and go to properties.

Select 'StoreGeneratedPattern' and choose 'Identity'.

I should point out that I am also new to Entity Framework but this worked for me. I just hope that when the model is updated that this setting is retained. It would be a pain if it wasn't.

Thanks,
Gray.